# How to find the probability of three independent random variables uniformly distributed?

Tags: statistics, probability

Problem:
Let X1, X2, X3 be three indep. random variables that are uniformly distributed btwn. 50 and 100.
a) Find the probability that the minimum of the three is btwn. 75 and 90.
b) Find the probability that the second smallest of the three is btwn. 75 and 90.

Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to the first part of your question

Without loss of generality let us assume x1 to be the minimum of the three numbers

```
P(x1<=x2) = P(x1<=x3) = (100 - x1 + 1) / (100-50+1) 
                                       ... sapmple space is invariant
```

For a known x1 sample, probability that it is the least of the three samples

```
F(xi) = P(x1 is the least of x1,x2,x3) =
    P(x1<=x2) & P(x1<=x3) = [(100-x1+1)/51]^2   ...  events are independant
```

Probability that xi is minimum and lies in the range (75 to 90)

```
=  Fractional area  under F(xi) curve over this range.
   sum_over {F(xi)} xi=75 to 90
=  ------------------------------
   sum_over {F(xi)} xi=50 to 100
```

I won't answer the second part as the above should give you enough clues
to proceed.

Hope this helps. I wish to acknowledge my colleague Tony Galati (Mathematician) who pointed out critical error in my initial analysis that omitted the normalizing denomenator, due to incorrect understanding that conditional probabalites of all posssible x_i in the desired range are simply additive.